method com.reactnativestripesdk. Stripe SDKModule.confirmPayment, parameter paymentIntentClientSecret
I don't know how to fix this problem. Someone please help me !
enter image description here
router.post("/create-payment-intent", async (req, res) => {
  const { items, user_id } = req.body;
  const customer = await stripe.customers.create();
  const ephemeralKey = await stripe.ephemeralKeys.create(
    { customer: customer.id },
    { apiVersion: '2024-04-10' }
  );
  try {
    const paymentIntent = await stripe.paymentIntents.create({
      amount: 1099,
      currency: 'usd',
      confirm: true,
      payment_method: 'pm_card_visa',
      payment_method_types: ['card'],
    });

    const response = {
      paymentIntent: paymentIntent.client_secret,
      ephemeralKey: ephemeralKey.secret,
      customer: customer.id,
      publishableKey: 'pk_test_51PA9vlRsfm3Ucs22ixDUZ8mt2Ki9E7WR4tSil67ONZD4dptsAwjVZ0J2IFNEEf0iHQhDNEaTT87f6mTD9dnY1lAW00TQcuO9MO'
    };

    return res.json(response);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
    return res.status(500).json({ error: 'An error occurred while creating Payment Intent' });
  }
});

My coding very very bad, i don't know how to fix that.
I know my code is wrong somewhere in here or missing a lot of things. I can identify what error I am facing but I can't fix it because I am not good at coding and this is my graduation project. I hope someone will help me and code for me to be able to fix the error! Please!
enter image description here
enter image description here
enter image description here
I don't know what happened for my code, I can't fix that
enter code here
The server reports that there is a secret_client but the application logs out like that

The error indicates that you are passing a null parameter where a non null one is expected.
Specifically, the paymentIntent.client_secret.
When you create your paymentIntent object, you should receive the client_secret as part of the response.
{
  "id": "pi_3MtwBwLkdIwHu7ix28a3tqPa",
  "object": "payment_intent",
  "amount": 2000,
  "amount_capturable": 0,
  "amount_details": {
    "tip": {}
  },
  "amount_received": 0,
  "application": null,
  "application_fee_amount": null,
  "automatic_payment_methods": {
    "enabled": true
  },
  "canceled_at": null,
  "cancellation_reason": null,
  "capture_method": "automatic",
  "client_secret": "pi_3MtwBwLkdIwHu7ix28a3tqPa_secret_YrKJUKribcBjcG8HVhfZluoGH",  /// <----- HERE
  "confirmation_method": "automatic",
  "created": 1680800504,
  "currency": "usd",
  "customer": null,
  "description": null,
  "invoice": null,
  "last_payment_error": null,
  "latest_charge": null,
  "livemode": false,
  "metadata": {},
  "next_action": null,
  "on_behalf_of": null,
  "payment_method": null,
  "payment_method_options": {
    "card": {
      "installments": null,
      "mandate_options": null,
      "network": null,
      "request_three_d_secure": "automatic"
    },
    "link": {
      "persistent_token": null
    }
  },
  "payment_method_types": [
    "card",
    "link"
  ],
  "processing": null,
  "receipt_email": null,
  "review": null,
  "setup_future_usage": null,
  "shipping": null,
  "source": null,
  "statement_descriptor": null,
  "statement_descriptor_suffix": null,
  "status": "requires_payment_method",
  "transfer_data": null,
  "transfer_group": null
}

I would follow the steps outlined in the documentation to make sure you are doing everything correctly, because it seems you are not getting the response back correctly or are getting a partial response.

My code last week still showed receive the client_secret as part full. But when I ran it again today, it said I needed to update the API, so I updated it. After the update is complete, it no longer shows full receive the client_secret as part, but instead shows something else. You can see the pictures below I added.

@TiênTriVũTrụ - if my answer helped you, please mark it as such. If you are encountering a different issue, post a new question. Please avoid adding answers which should be updates to the original question.

Your answer help me to fix bút it not work, I had comment below , you can see my new problem.  I don't know how to used this
